# Xamarin support for cognitive speech service

Tags: xamarin, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I want to use the Cognitive speech service (real-time continuous speech to text and interim results) in the **Xamarin** app. Is there any SDKs or plugin available? Since REST API has some limitations (no interim results), i am unable to go with it.

Comment: 2020 update, the C# SDK is available for Xamarin now and is working well on both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the SDK supports C# .NET and C++. We are expanding SDK support on other platforms. Support for .Netstandard and UWP will coming soon. Xamarin is also on our list. Please stay tuned.